# Second Order Necessary Condition for Optimality

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, optimization

> **Question:** [See context below.]
>
> What would be the analog of the Thm when $f$ is only defined on, say, a domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?
>
> In that case we can't take a general $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in the proof, so all we've got is positive semidefiniteness on $D$?
>
> Would the Cor still be true?

**Thm:** If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, then $x^*$ is a local minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ only if
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla f(x^*)=0,\\
H_f(x^*)\text{ is positive semidefinite}.
\end{cases}
$$
**Proof:** For $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$, expand $f(x^*+th)$ using Taylor's formula up to order $2$. Then one arrives at
$$
\langle H_f(x^*)h,h\rangle\geq0\quad(\forall h\in\mathbb{R}^n),
$$
which proves the theorem.

**Cor:** Since positive semidefiniteness is equivalent to having nonnegative principal minors, we see that in the case $n=2$ one must have $\Delta f(x^*)\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $h$ only refers to the direction. You would prove this by considering how $t \mapsto f(x^∗+th)$ behaves. So, all you need is that f is defined in a neighbourhood of $x^*$.